# Произношение слова "аллитерация"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно произносится слово "аллитерация" : с мягким или твердым [т]?

В словаре нашла произношение с твердым. Но в учебнике «Русский язык и культура речи: Учеб. для вузов /А. И. Дунев, М.Я. Дымарский, А.Ю. Кожевников и др.; Под ред. В.Д. Черняк» написано: *В большинстве слов основным вариантом становится мягкое произношение согласного, а вариант с твёрдым согласным является дополнительным, например:
агрессия [р'е] и доп. [рэ], аллитерация [т'е] и доп. [тэ]*…

Где-нибудь такое произношение зафиксировано?

Comment: Кошмарный учебник!!! Особенно поражает приведённое  в учебнике  в качестве допустимого считающееся в других словарях категорически неправильным твёрдое произношение [дэ] в слове _**дефицит**_. 

Comment: Какого года учебник?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня есть книга: Л.А. Введенская "**Словарь ударений** для работников радио и телевидения", "2012 г.

Там **алли(тэ)рация** и разг. **алли(те)рация.**

В словаре под ред Аванесова (1987) ***тэ*** и доп. ***те***

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что слово является примером того, как со временем меняется литературное произношение (приблизительно за 50 лет).

• "Словарь ударений для работников радио и телевидения" (Ф. Л. Агеенко и М. В. Зарва, под редакцией Д. Э. Розенталя, **1967**, печатный вариант):
***аллитера́ция*** (то есть только *[**те**]*, без каких-либо пометок).

•• **Сегодня** же правильным считается твердое произношение ([Русское словесное ударение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F); [Орфоэпический словарь русского языка: норма и ее варианты, **2017**](https://irorb.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/slovar-orfoepicheskij-o.v.pryadilnikova.pdf)):
***аллитерáция**, –и [**тэ**]*.